# Matcha.io doesn't work for Plots?

Tags: plot, editors, online

I like to use the free online edit matcha.io (https://www.mathcha.io/) which is in my view very nice for generating figures but I am realizing it is not able to convert plots in latex code. Is it correct?
It works fine with diagrams but not plots.

I made a simple rotated scatter plot (as example), to see the result.

[image]

But when converting to Latex code I find only a very simple `tikz` code which is not generating any plot in Latex document:

```
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,402); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 402


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Do someone knows why this very useful online tool doesn't work with this kind of plots?

Thank you in advance for every reply.

Giacomo

Comment: Or you work without a login with username and password or it is not possible to extract a code in TikZ.

Comment: Also logging in the code is mostly empty

Comment: Hence, it is not possible to have an image and export it in TikZ-code.